# Use a global variable for different locations (path)

Tags: nginx, lua

I have a rental location where I want to register a variable `aet` with a certain value.

```
 location /aet {
    default_type 'text/plain';
        content_by_lua '
          if ngx.var.host:match("(.*).nexus$") ~= nil then 
             aet = ngx.var.host:match("(.-)%.")
             ngx.say(aet)
          end
        ';
 }
```

And I want to use this variable in another rental location / getIp`

```
location /getIp {
    default_type 'application/json';
    rds_json          on;

    content_by_lua '
        postgres_pass     database;
        postgres_query  "SELECT ip FROM establishment_view WHERE aet = aet";
        postgres_output rds;
    ';
}
```

I want the variable `aet` to initialize without needing to call path `/ aet`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use [Data Sharing within an Nginx Worker](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#data-sharing-within-an-nginx-worker)

But if you really need **global** variable for all worker processes you may use [ngx.shared.DICT](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxshareddict) API

```
 http {
     lua_shared_dict my_dict 10m;
     server {
         location /aet {
             content_by_lua_block {
                 local my_dict = ngx.shared.my_dict 
                 my_dict :set("aet", ngx.var.host:match("(.-)%."))
             }
         }
         location /getIp {
             set $aet = ""
             access_by_lua_block {
                 local my_dict = ngx.shared.my_dict 
                 ngx.var.aet = my_dict:get("aet")
             }
             postgres_pass     database;
             postgres_query  "SELECT ip FROM establishment_view WHERE aet = aet";
             postgres_output rds;
         }
     }
 }
```

PS: Your nginx configuration snippet is wrong - you use nginx directives postgres_* within content_by_lua.

Also all *by_lua are deprecated, use *_by_lua_block. It will save you a lot time with escaping.

Comment: Thank you very much it works. You save me a lot of time. 
But why should I use _*by_lua_blocks_ instead of _*by_lua_?

Comment: https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#special-escaping-sequences